# Using one table to filter another one without join

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql

I have two tables/csv files. Table 1 has only one column, in date format. Table 2 has customer id, join and leave dates. I want to make a list of all active customers for each day in the first table. Such as Table2.Join date < Table1.date < Table2.leave date. The output will be a new csv/table with two columns: Date and a list of all active customers.

Using Pandas I did the following, and I am looking for a way to improve it if possible, or implement it in SQL:

```
# Create a new column 
Table1['active_customers'] = Table1.date

for index, date in Table1.iterrows():
    Table1.active_customers[index] = Table2.loc[(Table2.date_joined <= date) \\
                                      & ((Table2.date_left > date) | 
                                          Table2.date_left.isnull())].user
```

The tables are as follows:

```
Table 1
date
2010-12-09
2015-04-12
2018-10-27

Table 2
user  date_joined date_left
uid1  2006-01-09  2011-10-26
uid2  2008-05-18  2013-04-19
uid3  2010-11-29  2016-07-01
uid4  2011-09-16  2011-12-09
uid5  2013-11-17  
uid6  2015-05-31  
uid7  2019-06-20  

Output:
date        active_users
2010-12-09  uid1, uid2, uid3
2015-04-12  uid3, uid5
2018-10-27  uid5, uid6
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide some actual example data and an example of desired output. I for one am not sure what ' ...list of all existing customers` means?

Comment: @Manakin the question is tagged with `postgresql`.

Comment: thanks @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for warnings. I added more data and the expected output

Comment: For each date in Table1 I need a list of active users whose join and leave dates present in Table2. I'm looking for a solution either in Pandas or SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe OP's issue with "don't have conditions on dates" stems from a misconception that JOINS can only be done between PK-FK combinations. This is incorrect; you can join on just about anything (more to come). For the issue at hand a join solution would be:

```
select t1.t1_date "Date" 
     , string_agg(t2.uid, ',') "Active Users" 
  from table2 t2
  join table1 t1
    on (    t1.t1_date >= t2.date_joined 
        and (t1.t1_date < t2.date_left or t2.date_left is null)
       )  
  group by t1.t1_date 
  order by t1.t1_date
;
```

See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9b32d050a9de7bb828e79d4be7789a18). Note: I changed column names DATE and USER. Both are Data Types and/or Reserved Words. Using either as column names is very poor practice.  

So back to JOIN. As I indicated above you can you can join on just about anything. All that is needed is getting the data type being joined being comparable and that only as long as you have multiple predicates is a condition.  The join condition join expression does not even have to be in in the joined tables/views. The fiddle captains an example on a column that does not exist in the CTEs. The short of it being "do not assume you cannot join, if that is the appropriate approach then do it, or at least write test condition(s).

Comment: Thank you very much for teaching this to me! I thought I always needed primary and foreign keys for joining tables. I have one more question: the for loop I share above, your solution and the @Stefanov.sm's solution below they all result in different number of users... Although yours and Stefanov.sm's are closer to each other. What do you think about it? Also my dataset's size is 50K, these queries result in min 200K rows for each date

Comment: You are welcome. As far as your difference with your loop I really cannot comment, I do not know Pandas. But as far as my query and @Stefanov.sm's they produce identical results. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ef1b62b1d20f02649745038074498178). Notice the last query which actually shows the difference between them - there is none.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple to implement it in SQL:

```sql
select
  t1.date,
  (
   select string_agg(user, ',')
     from table2 t2
     where t1.date >= t2.date_joined 
     and (t1.date < t2.date_left or t2.date_left is null)
  ) active_users
from table1 t1;
```

Is there a specific reason why to not use `join`?

Comment: I don't have the condition on dates, such as: t1.date = t2.data_joined. Might be my low SQL skills, I thought this is not joining two tables, plus I don't have the matching keys

Comment: I am not sure I understand "I don't have conditions on dates". Do you mean comparison operators? Does the above solve your problem? Well, you can join tables by expression, not just matching keys.